# Script with getopts doesn't assign value to variable

Tags: linux, bash, variables, parameters, getopts

The variable MAANDINT doesn't get a value assigned.
Please help me to find a solution

```
#!/bin/bash

if [ $# -eq 0 ]
then
echo Je moet een maand ingeven!
exit 1
elif [ $# -eq 1 ]
then
JAAR=$(date +'%Y')
else
JAAR=$2
fi

while getopts ":jan:feb:maa:apr:mei:jun:jul:aug:sep:okt:nov:dec:" MAAND;
do
case $MAAND in
jan)
MAANDINT=1
;;
feb)
MAANDINT=2
;;
maa)
MAANDINT=3
;;
apr)
MAANDINT=4
;;
mei)
MAANDINT=5
;;
jun)
MAANDINT=6
;;
jul)
MAANDINT=7
;;
aug)
MAANDINT=8
;;
sep)
MAANDINT=9
;;
okt)
MAANDINT=10
;;
nov)
MAANDINT=11
;;
dec)
MAANDINT=12
;;
*)
echo Deze maand bestaat niet!
exit 1
;;
esac
done
echo $MAANDINT
```

Comment: `getopts` does not support long options. `MAAND` will never match any of those values. Add `echo "$MAAND"` in the `*` case.

Comment: Thnx for the help, we fixed it with if and elifs

Comment: Use [`getopt`](http://www.unix.com/man-page/linux/1/getopt/) instead.

Comment: Thnx for the tip but we tried it with getopt and it still wasn't working well. But it's fixed now so thnx all for the effort :)

Answer (score 0):

`getopts` does not support long options. `MAAND` will never match any of those values. Add `echo "$MAAND"` in the `*` case.
                    – Etan Reisner